# Import a library that imports a GPL library?

Tags: python, licensing

So I am importing a library ([reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/)), which is licensed BSD, but itself uses [some](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/pyrxp/) libraries that are licensed GPL.

My question is, if I import reportlab into python - do I have to abide by BSD or GPL license?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IANAL either, <strike>but I think it doesn't even come into play as long as you are not going to distribute the other software as well. For example, if you just tell your users "you have to install pyRXP in order to use this" (maybe easier if you make that "reportlab"), I think the GPL does not apply to your own code.</strike>

EDIT: While there is no problem with using the reportlab toolkit in this particular case, the above interpretation does not seem to be correct (see agf's comments on this answer below, as well as his own answer)

Note that the reportlab toolkit (although it's by the same company "ReportLab") doesn't necessarily use pyRXP. They are two different things, each with it's own license.

Looking at reportlab's source code, in `reportlab.lib.rparsexml`, it seems that pyRXP is only imported if it is installed (separately, because it is not included), and it uses another xml parser if pyRXP is not available. (I guess this is their way of allowing pyRXP to be used, and still keeping reportlab under BSD license)

But maybe you'd best ask on the [reportlab mailing list](http://two.pairlist.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/)...

Comment: No. If your code is a derivative of pyRXP, you have to distribute your code under the GPL, whether or not you distribute or made changes to pyRXP.

Comment: @agl: Thanks, but could you expand a little on this/point to where you can find this. To me at least, this is not clear. GPLv2 explicitly states "Activities other than copying, distribution and modification are not covered by this License". So, at least for GPLv2, why/where am I wrong? GPLv3... I'm not sure. (but RXP, and hence pyRXP too, uses GPLv2) See also the addition to my answer.

Comment: "You must cause any work that you distribute or publish, that in whole or in part contains or is __derived__ from the Program or any part thereof, to be licensed as a whole at no charge to all third parties __under the terms of this License__."

Comment: @agf: sorry, should have been "agf" instead of "agl"

Comment: @agf: This also only occurs in GPLv2 ;-) Wouldn't that be incompatible with the other clause I mentioned, unless "activities other than copying, distribution and modification" do not constitute a "derived" work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. The idea is that creating a derived work is the same as adding new code to the existing work, and so is a form of modification, and redistributing it is a form of distribution under the previous clause.

Comment: Well, it was totally non-obvious to me that "import" (as in python) of a library that you do not redistribute, would count as "a form of modification". Of course, if that is the case (of which I'm still not 100% convinced, but I'll take your word for it ;-)), it makes sense that you are bound by the GPL. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: The core question is, if my code __can't work__ without the GPL'd code, did I really create something separate, or is it an addition to what already existed? So if some your code doesn't work without the GPL'd module, that code has to be distributed under the GPL. I know I'm basically repeating myself, but that's the way to think about it in order to understand how the GPL is applied, and also it's intent.

Comment: Understood! (this would also imply by the way, that in the OP's case: reportlab's *optional* use of pyRXP (for performance) does not imply that he has to GPL his code when he uses the (BSD-licensed) reportlab)

Comment: Yep, I said that in another comment above: "And just don't use their XML parser -- that way you're definitely just bound by the BSD license." I'm going to edit my answer to add a bit of what we've been talking about.

Comment: @agf: great, you definitely earned my upvote ;-)

Comment: This seems to me the most commonsense approach. I am surprised there is no definitive answer to this, but only speculations. If I must choose between speculations - I'll choose the one that suites me best.

Comment: @agf: good idea, done (sorry it took a while ;-))

Answer (score 8):

IANAL. You have to abide by the licenses of all the packages you're using.

However, most would say if you only use the public API of those libraries, and they could theoretically be swapped out for other libraries implementing the same API, your code does not fall under the GPL, only any modifications you make to those libraries.

This is the point of view taken by the Linux kernel development community, for example.

Edit: After looking at the site of reportlab, it is clear that if you **don't use the PyXML parser** then you're only bound by the BSD license, as you're not using any GPL'd code.

Also, the question was raised in the comments whether your code is affected by the GPL if you don't distribute any GPL'd packages because the GPL primarily deals with modification of the code under the license and redistribution of that code. The answer is that if your code is a **derivative work** of the GPL'd code, you have to license your code under the GPL **whether or not** you're redistributing the original GPL'd code.

Comment: See my edit. The Linux Kernel is GPL not LGPL, and they take the point of view that proprietary drivers are OK, because they are not "derivative works" of Linux, they simply implement some APIs. We're both editing at the same time. Many distributions include binary modules standard, and that is not relevent: if the GPL doesn't allow this every company making a binary driver would be in violation, including AMD and NVidia, just off the top of my head.

Comment: Just to be clear, I was responding to a commentor who deleted his comment.

Comment: So, the safe bet is not to use reportlab, in our commercially redistributable software?

Comment: This is the point of view of some kernel developers. The kernel also uses a publicly documented API - it's largely POSIX compliant. IF someone offers header files for a new thing that are GPLed, any other implementation would necessarily copy the code from the interface and have to be GPL. You can't compare an API from a published standard to a custom one, and essentially claim anyone can violate the GPL at will.

Comment: It's the de-facto position of all kernel developers, because they're knowingly agreeing to license their code to corporations who take that stance, and knowingly placing their code under the control of people who take that stance (Linus). Also, the Linux API dwarfs the POSIX API and much of it is not part of any standard outside the Linux API itself.

Comment: The license FAQ you link to clearly says you can reuse reportlab in a proprietary manner, with the exception of their XML parser. So @drozzy -- do you need to use their parser? It sounds like reportlab can be used without it.

Comment: That's the thing - I never install they parser explicitly, but only use reportlab. I just need to create a few damn pdfs! lol

Comment: Have you tried deleting the parser and seeing if your code still works?

Comment: No, but really, I don't wish to go into such detail. In my opinion if the software says BSD on it - it should be BSD. I should not care what other pieces it uses.

Comment: @drozzy Carefully read the comments I posted on the response you accepted. If you distribute code that uses reportlab's parser, your code is also licensed under the GPL. The FAQ on reportlab's site also says this.

Comment: Thanks, but could you point where it says that? It only says that I have to "negotiate" with them about using pyRXP: http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/faq/

Comment: "Negotiate" means __buy a commercial license__. There are three options: pay for a non-GPL license from them (so you're not using their code under the GPL, and so yours doesn't have to be, either), use it under the GPL (and distribute your code under the GPL), or use the BSD part of reportlab but NOT the GPL'd parser (and distribute your code however you want).

Answer (score 3):

IANAL. From section 1.3 of the reportlab page here:[reportlab licensing](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/faq/#1.3) you can see they want you to talk to them about a commercial license.

GPL code when linked to BSD code requires you to license the BSD code under GPL - I'm talking static linking here. Dynamic linking to GPLed code is not allowed by non-GPL software - in fact, this is the reason for the existence of the LGPL license which allows dynamic linking from non-(L)GPL code. There is also an exception in the glibc license because they want you to be able to build commercial software with it.

The Linux Kernel developers do not all agree on all aspects of linking issues. If you're building against a standard API (POSIX) then it seems obvious you don't need to be GPL. But their arguments go deeper than that, so I don't think there is a direct comparison.

From the link above: "yRXP, our XML parser, is under the GNU General Public License. This is because the RXP parser underneath it is under this license. If you want to use pyRXP in a closed source project, you have to negotiate with us." This suggests they own pyRPX and can give or sell you a different license for it.

That's similar to the pyQT issue. You can make GPLed software with it, but for commercial stuff you need to pay up. Unless you want to make a commercial product that is GPLed of course.

Comment: Also, I find this argument weird. In GPL it does not say that we need to "open source" our own code, but only the modifications to the code that was GPL. When I am "importing" code in python - how am I modifying it? What is the issue here?

Comment: The GPL says that you need to license under the GPL not just changes to the GPL'd code (that's the LGPL) but also any code that is derived from it. The question is what counts as code that derives from it.

Comment: In the case of static linking, the executable is a derived work (directly derived from source in fact) so all the source code must be provided with GPL licensing. For dynamic linking, the argument is that your internal data structures and function calls are still derived from the GPLed definitions (or something like that), and so your running software is a derived work and must be GPL licensed and offer source code. IMHO the static linking argument is a slam dunk and the dynamic linking one is a little weak, but not bad. Neither has failed in court thus far.

Comment: So when I do "import blah" in python, is that static or dynamic linking? Also - how in the world can I go and check what reportlab "imports" or "links" etc... Should it not be their problem? If they say BSD - should I not only worry about that?

Comment: drozzy - It's the equivalent of static linking. And just don't use their XML parser -- that way you're definitely just bound by the BSD license. @phkahler -- I don't believe either has been tested in court, just the part where you have to distribute changes made to a GPL project, and code that is clearly derived from it.